# Float two div's next to each other even when you resize your browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I got two div's that i floated left and right.

```
<div style="float:left">1</div>
<div style="float:right">1</div>
<div style="clear:both">1</div>
```

So everything works fine, i do it for years this way.
Now i code a RESONSIVE-DESIGN so i cant work with fixed width's.
The problem is the following: if the screen getting less the right div is situated BELOW the left one. I dont want this.

I know i can do fixed width's to overcome this or put both in a wrapper to overcome this too BUT as i said - i cant work with fixed width's.

How can i handle the collapse that both divs are beside each other and not below or something (when change the screen to small size)

im new in responsive but i get all to wokr - thats my last problem and i always worked with fixed size values in the past.

Comment: Look at `media queries`.

Comment: When I first started with responsive it was useful to start using existing frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) - this includes a grid framework that takes into consideration responsive layouts, and there are so many examples of it in action.

Media queries are a CSS conditional syntax that let you add custom styles based on conditions like screen width; effectively allowing you a way to style a module different ways for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this to an extent.

HTML markup

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;

}
#one{
    width:50%;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
#two{
    width:50%;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/2ag8W/)

well the better way is to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
Using **media queries** you can target specific screen resolutions which will always be a plus point to achieve **responsive design**.

Comment: An update with `media queries` - http://jsfiddle.net/2ag8W/1/ (if the viewport is less than 480px)